# index out of range exception in AMOS

Tags: amos

I was working with IBM AMOS drawing a model, and suddenly a window with an error message displayed and kept displaying every time I tried to go along with the work. The message is :

Index out of range exception

Do you have any idea howa to solve this?

Thank you

I closed the software and started over, but the same thing happened. I've many solutions that have nothing to do with my problems. I don't know what are these codes and where I should be writing them. I don't know if the problem is related to AMOS or something else.

I cleaned out my database, I thought maybe it's the cause behind this message, but it didn't work either.